# migrating from Linux to Windows, but my templates aren't loading

Tags: templating, server

Hello I am migrating our craft install from a Linux server to a Windows IIS based server.

So far all is working, however the default template is not loading. Any idea why?

Linux: http:// 70 .32 .84 .65/home
Windows: https://brownbis.com/primer/home

Is there a PHP module on Windows that I need to enable?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your craft/templates folder on the Windows box has the default template that Craft ships out-of-the-box with and not the custom templates and front-end resources that you've designed.

Make sure your correct files are actually in `craft/templates`.

Comment: Hello Brad, I just confirmed that all my modified files are in the craft/templates folder, but they are not being honored. If I delete the templates folder, I get an error, but when I put it back, only the default craft templates are loading. Is there a twig config setting that differs on Windows systems?

Comment: @BalaPeterson It looks like you got it up and running?